# How do I read integer in 8086 assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, integer, x86-16

I know that we can input strings and characters in 8086, but how can we input integers?
Is it just through *converting* the input **string** to an **integer**?

Comment: You can only read characters from a keyboard, you have to convert them to integers. What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you don't want to write your own conversion function and if you have access to the C runtime library, then you can use `atoi` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but when i needed to do it in studies we just converted it manually and it was accepted solution. Didactician didn't tell us about better method.

Comment: thank you!was it through converting string using its ascii code?!